# what's the meaning of match in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

i am sorry i am a newbie of regular expression. i searched this match from the internet. but don't know what's the match meaning. expect some one can explain it to me. many thanks.

```
if (window.location.pathname.match(/^\/test\//i))
```

i know `window.location.pathname` will  get the current URL path excluding the domain name.but don't know what's the  meaning of the part in the match method.

Comment: I renamed and retagged the post; the `match` function has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info. References on regexes are _easy_ to find.

Comment: *match* is a method of *String.prototype*, not *RegExp*. The argument doesn't have to be a regular expression, but it can be (and often is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/^\/test\//i` means regular expression (`/.../`) that starts (`^`) with forward slash (`\/`) followed by the word `test` followed by forward slash (`\/`) insensitive to case (`i`).

So it will match url that is `/TEST/whatever-goes-here` but not `/this/test/url`

Comment: i refered the regular expressions manual, it says i Case-insensitive.why you said case insensitive? thank you.

Comment: case sensitive means that regex:`test` can only match `test` and not `Test` but insensitive meanse that regex:`test` can match `test` and also `TeSt` etc... to make a regex pattern insensitive, put `i` as a flag, so in javascript it goes after the delimiting `/` at the end like this `/regex-pattern/i`

Answer (score 2):

[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) tests a string using a regular expression. In this case, `location.pathname` is being tested to see if it starts with `/test/`, case insensitive.

For example, the statements after the `if` will executed if the `location.pathname` is any of the following:

```
/test/
/TEST/
/test/random
/TEST/foo
```

but not any of these:

```
/
/testing/
/foo
```

Comment: if i want to case sensitive, how should i do? change the character i to which? thank you

Comment: Just take the `i` after the regular expression out.

Answer (score 0):

The [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method on a JavaScript string will search for a match between a regular expression and a string, and return the matches. If the match method does not find a match, it returns null. If it finds a match, match returns an array.

This method is on the string object, and is not part of jQuery, but of JavaScript/EcmaScript.